# Date advancing disable in angular datepicker

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material2

See screenshot below. I have changed date manually to 35/08/2018 (DD/MM/YYYY). In this case angular date picker changes it to 04/09/2018 (Advancing date by 4 days after 31st Aug ).
 What should be done to restrict this behavior and to make 35st Aug as wrong/ invalid date.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this turn out to be default behavior. To change it we have to add manual validation only.